# Passing Space Issue In Codeigniter Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have  a codeigniter application.In that i call the controller function using ajax/jquery.But when i passing variable with space value it becomes wrong loading of another view page.

This is my view page code

```
var cnt=$("#search_agency_res").serialize();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/addAgency/agency_map_result/"+region+"/"+country+"/"+agency,
    data: cnt,
    success: function(valmsgnew){
    $("#map").css("display","block");
    $("#map").html(valmsgnew).show();
    }
    });
```

`search_agency_res` is the name of form.Here the variable `region` must have values in all time but `country,agency` may have ""(space).How can i handle this?

The issue is only occuring when `country,agency` have sapce or null value.If it have any valid value except space then everything is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing data as post:

```
var cnt=$("#search_agency_res").serialize();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "index.php/addAgency/agency_map_result,
    data: "cnt="+cnt+"&rregion="+region+"&country="+country+"&agency="+agency,
    success: function(valmsgnew){
    $("#map").css("display","block");
    $("#map").html(valmsgnew).show();
    }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If i use this how can i get this variable in controller